# C# Dictionary Sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

When I try to sort the dictionary before the traversing, it doesn't work. I believe it is because dictionary in C# is immutable? Is there any work around this?

```
if (arrFilter[i].strTitle.Equals("test")) {
    arrFilter[i].dicValue.OrderBy(j => j.Key, new AlphaNumericComparator());
    } else {
    arrFilter[i].dicValue.OrderBy(j => j.Key, new numComp());
}

foreach (var item in arrFilter[i].dicValue.OrderBy(j => j.Key, new AlphaNumericComparator())) {
// Traversing stuff

}
```

Comment: **1.** Please include variable declarations (e.g. for `arrFilter` and the type containing `strTitle` and `dicValue` members) in your code snippet. **2.** What exactly do you mean by saying, "It doesn't work"?

Answer (score 4):

The `OrderBy` method you're using is a LINQ Extension method which in this instance returns an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<,>>`.  It doesn't sort the dictionary in place, nor does it return a sorted dictionary.  It simply enumerates the dictionary and returns a sorted enumerable.  This is why you have to call it when traversing (or at least use its return value when traversing).

Note also the dictionary is mutable (contrary to your belief). Its ordering, however, is not under your control.  IF you want to control the ordering, you might consider using [`SortedDictionary<,>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: To be very pedantic "returns a sorted enumerable" should be "returns enumerable that will eventually return sorted items when/if enumerated". It also surprisingly does not fail when you add items to dictionary between getting result of `dictionary.OrderBy(...)` and actual enumeration...

Answer (score 1):

You could simply convert your *Dictionary* to a *List*.  In essence:

```
// var (List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
var container = myDictionary.ToList();    
container.Sort((index, nextIndex) =>
{
     return index.Value.CompareTo(nextIndex.Value);
});
```

That will provide the *Sort* or *Order* capabilities that aren't included in the *Dictionary Collection* already.  Hopefully this helps.